# How to use a .NET DLL in Powerbuilder 9

Tags: .net, dll, powerbuilder

I created a DLL using VB 2008. After building my project I have Both (.DLL and .TLB) files created.

To test, I wrote a client in  VB 2008 with native use of the DLL (Works fine)  and a VB 6 client, Creating the dependency via the TLB file and every works fine as well.

My customer uses PowerBuilder 9 and I cannot get the reference to any of the DLL´s functions. Because of that I assume it needs to use the .TLB instead.

My questions are:
 AM I right? Is there an actual way to map the TLB file in PB9?

Is it possible, at all, to use .NET DLLs in PB 9 or it´s corresponding .TLB?

Thanks in advance.

Jose

Answer (score 0):

Uffe's link creates a COM Callable Wrapper which will work with all versions of PB.

I found the following video tutorial and link helpful

http://www.powerbuildertv.com/index.php/en/archived-webinars/powerbuilder/267-using-net-assemblies-with-powerbuilder

http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/258395

If your .NET DLL is non-visual and already COM-Visible you may only have to register it with REGASM.